# Jinja2 / Flask - Re-using a base template many times in one page

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have common base elements of my site which I was to re-use multiple times on one page.

In one site, there will be multiple dropdowns with each having a different set of dropdowns.

Currently, I use `render_template` in the following way:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
   
    return render_template('LandingPage.html',
                           FileName='Hi.png', relatedlist=['NewUser',"OtherNewUser"])
```

I am using bulma for my select form which looks like:

```
<div class="select">

    <select name="{{FileName|safe}}">

        {% for val in relatedlist%}
        <option href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            {{val}}
        </option>

        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Now, my main page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 {% include "LandingPage.html" %}

</body>
</html>
```

If I wanted to re-use this select list multiple times in the `LandingPage.html`, how would I do that given `Filename` and `relatedlist` are a one-to-one mapping being pushed from my python code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a file with [macros](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#macros) for bulma.
For your dropdown it would look something like this.

```
{# macros/bulma.html -#}
{% macro select(name, values) -%}
{% set cls = kwargs.pop('class_') or kwargs.pop('class') -%}
  <div class="select{{(' ' + cls) if cls else ''}}"{{kwargs|xmlattr}}>
    <select name="{{name}}">
      {% for v in values -%}
      <option value="{{v}}">{{v}}</option>
      {% endfor -%}
    </select>
  </div>
{%- endmacro %}
```

You can then import this file into a template and reuse the macro for various dropdowns.

```
{% import 'macros/bulma.html' as bulma -%}
{% for i in range(10) -%}
{{ bulma.select(filename, related_list, class_='is-primary') }}
{% endfor -%}
```